# How to check the running time of program in python

Tags: python

I am new to python, and I need to check the time of running the codes in python.
The codes are shown below:

```
np.random.seed(42)
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x_1,y_1,test_size=0.2)
clf=SVC(kernel='rbf',probability=True)
clf.fit(x_train,np.ravel(y_train))
clf.score(x_test,y_test)
```

Appreciate a lot if any advices!

Comment: Use `timeit`- https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `time`

```
import time
np.random.seed(42)
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
start = time.time()
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x_1,y_1,test_size=0.2)
clf=SVC(kernel='rbf',probability=True)
clf.fit(x_train,np.ravel(y_train))
clf.score(x_test,y_test)
end = time.time()
print("Time taken {}".format(end - start))
```

In general

```
import time
start = time.time()
# do something
end = time.time()
print("Time taken {}".format(end - start))
```

Comment: Use `monotonic()` or `perf_counter()` instead of `time()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use timeit python library. Otherwise, in your case you can use below code.

```py
from time import perf_counter, sleep
start = perf_counter()
sleep(2)
end = perf_counter()
print(f'Time required: {(end - start)}')
```